# Laravel/PHP renaming associative keys without knowing their names

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-collection

Given following collection/array:

```
[
    "somename" => "test.test.be"
    "anothername" => "test"
    "yetanothername" => "testing"
    "extrafield" => "extra",
    "extrafield" => "extra",

]
```

When i retrieve this collection i always know the order of them, but i will not know the key-names. So what i want to do is transform this collection and change the keynames to my defined values.

For a non-associative array i would do something like

```
    $trimmedCollection->transform(function ($item) {
        return [
            'email'               => $item[0],
            'first_name'          => $item[1],
            'surname'             => $item[2],
        ];
    });
```

But how would i handle this for the given collection? Also what to do with overflow items. Say i suddenly got 10 key-value pairs but only wrote a transform for 3 how would i transform all the overflow to a default key?

**Edit:**
For the overflow items i would like to assign all extra fields in the given array to be stored like so.

Below would be the final array:

```
[
    "email" => "test.test.be"
    "first_name" => "test"
    "surname" => "testing"
    "additional_fields" => ["key-name" => "extra","key-name" => "extra"]

]
```

Where the key-name is the original name of the key i retrieved.

Comment: Please elaborate on the 'overflow items' part with example input and desired output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_shift` to remove the 1st element in the array for every known element, and add the remaining array to your `additional_fields` key:

```
$trimmedCollection->transform(function ($item) {

    return [
        'email'               => array_shift($item), //$item[0]
        'first_name'          => array_shift($item), //$item[1]
        'surname'             => array_shift($item), //$item[2]
        'additional_fields'   => $item //all remaining items
    ];
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For the overflow items : all remaining items in the collection should have the the key assigned of  'additional_fields' and the data would be stored in a json table. I hope that is clear enough

Comment: @Christophvh could you add example input and desired output for this to your question, so i am clear of your requirements.

Comment: @Christophvh I made the ammends

Comment: I did not know that about array_shift. You rock sir! Thank you very much

Comment: No problem, glad i could help you

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this to transform your selected keys. This retains the other values with their unchanged keys.

```
function replace_array_key(array &$item, $oldKey, $newKey)
{
    $item[$newKey] = $item[$oldKey];
    unset($item[$oldKey]);
}

$trimmedCollection->transform(function ($item) {
    replace_array_key($item, 'somename', 'email');
    replace_array_key($item, 'anothername', 'first_name');
    replace_array_key($item, 'yetanothername', 'surname');

    return $item;
});
```

You can even extend this to an array list of old and new key names and run it through and arrap_map.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is a interesting approach that works too! But i went with the array_shift solution.

Comment: @Christophvh np, i didn't see the edit on moving the other values to a sub array. I'd go with steve's solution as well. Also remember the shift works based on the item order, you might want to tweak it to shift based on keys in case your item order changes.